# log4j:ERROR JDBCAppender::flush_buffer(), : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Tags: java, mysql, sql, log4j

I am using log4j for logging in my web application. Its working fine. But whenever i start my tomcat server i get the below exception :

```
log4j:ERROR JDBCAppender::flush_buffer(), : 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYPROJECT?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&autoReconnect=true
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCDefaultConnectionHandler.getConnection(JDBCDefaultConnectionHandler.java:77)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCDefaultConnectionHandler.getConnection(JDBCDefaultConnectionHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCLogger.prepareConnection(JDBCLogger.java:489)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCLogger.append(JDBCLogger.java:555)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender.flush_buffer(JDBCAppender.java:887)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender.append(JDBCAppender.java:867)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:203)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:853)
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.doLogf(Log4jLogger.java:53)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logf(Logger.java:2112)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger.recognizedObsoleteHibernateNamespace(CoreMessageLogger_$logger.java:2397)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DTDEntityResolver.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity(EJB3DTDEntityResolver.java:59)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2015)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1971)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:734)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:457)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: How will it work fine if you are getting errors on startup of tomcat? Have you Put the mysql-connector jar inside the lib directory of the tomcat directory?

Comment: Yes. mysql connector jar is in lib folder. application is launched successfully.. but getting that excepion while server start up. log4j is not detecting the jar.. how to solve this issue

Comment: is the connector jar in your applications lib directory? if your application has started and you are getting this issue then your application is not able to find this jar.

Comment: connector jar is in my applications lib and also in tomcat lib. but still i get this error. log4j is unable to detect the drive. how to solve this issue ??